# Python Webdriver I have a class defined but from the unittest TestCase class I cannot see the class methods

Tags: python, class, methods, selenium-webdriver

I am automating our website with Webdriver, Python.
I have a class called administrationPage.py with some methods defined e.g. def add_project(self) method which adds a project in the GUI

I have the TestCase class called AdministrationPage_TestCase and a method called  def add_Project(self):
In this method I instantiate, declare the administionPage.py class.  E.g.
administration_page = administrationPage(self.driver)
From administration_page I want to call the add_project method.
When i type in administration_page.  when i press . it should appear with a pop up with a list of methods from the class.
It is not showing the pop up with the available methods of the class.

My LoginPage_TestCase.py and LoginPage.py i have implemented in the same way & that is ok.  I can see the method userLogin_valid() which is defined in the LoginPage class.

Do you know what i have missed or done wrong?

My code snippet is below.  Thanks.

AdministrationPage.py

```
from element import BasePageElement
from locators import MainPageLocators
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import time
import datetime

class BasePage(object):

    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver

class administrationPage(BasePage):

    def get_date_now(self):
            date_now = datetime.datetime.now()
            print str(date_now)

    # Add a project, enter project name & description, save
    def add_project(self):
        add_project_button = self.driver.find_element(*MainPageLocators.addButton_project)
        add_project_button.click()
        project_name_textfield = self.driver.find_element(*MainPageLocators.projectName_textfield)
        project_name_textfield.click()
        project_name_textfield.clear()
        dateNow = self.get_date_now()
        project_name_textfield.sendkeys('LADEMO_IE_nn_')
        project_description_textfield = self.driver.find_element(*MainPageLocators.projectDescription_textfield)
        project_description_textfield.click()
        project_description_textfield.clear()
        project_name_textfield.sendkeys("LADEMO create a basic project test script - Selenium Webdriver/Python Automated test")
```

AdministrationPage_TestCase.py

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
import page
import administrationPage
import time

class AdministrationPage_TestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Ie("C:\QA\Automation\Python_projects\Selenium Webdriver\IEDriverServer_Win32_2.45.0\IEDriverServer.exe")
        self.driver.get("http://riaz-pc.company.local:8080/clearcore")
        self.login_page = page.LoginPage(self.driver)
        time.sleep(15)

    def add_Project(self):
        login_page = page.LoginPage(self.driver)
        login_page.userLogin_valid()
        administration_page = administrationPage(self.driver)
        administration_page.

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to solve it now.

```
administration_page = administrationPage.administrationPage(self.driver)
administration_page.add_project()
```